# Swift cannot assign value of type 'UINavigationController'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a newbie at Swift so I'm just learning. I am following a tutorial on youtube and I keep getting this error. Let's Build That App : How to build Twitter.'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

For the  `window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController` it says

> cannot assign value of type 'UINavigationController' to type
>   UIViewController?' Expression of type'(rootViewController:
>   HomeController)' is unused

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // ignore storyboard.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let homeController = HomeContoller(collectionViewLayout:
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController
        (rootViewController: homeController)

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Comment: Did you put a space between UINavigationController and the ( ?

Comment: window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController
        (rootViewController: homeController)

Change this line to

window?.rootViewController = homeController

It says you cannot assign UINavigationController as it requires a UIViewController.

Comment: @ManishPathak but a UINavigationController is a UIViewController.

Comment: @luk2302  you are correct, what is the super class of HomeController? 


This is working
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifierStringRootVC")
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav1
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: @JasonSprague remove any line breaks between "UINavigationController" and "("

Comment: @Jason Sprague 
What is the superclass of HomeController? 
Since you are assigning 
UINavigationController
        (rootViewController: homeController)
homeController must be of type of UIViewController.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the line break between these **two** lines:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController
    (rootViewController: homeController)
```

The first line:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController
```

produces this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'UINavigationController.Type' to type 'UIViewController?'

and the second line:

```
(rootViewController: homeController)
```

produces this warning:

> Expression of type '(rootViewController: HomeController)' is unused

If you remove the line break, both will go away:

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navigationController")

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Note: You need to put the storyboard id "navigationController" to your navigationController